# Is the commensurator of a tree lattice a simple group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, lattices, topological-groups

Let $T$ be an $n$-regular tree ($n\geq3$).  Let $\operatorname{Aut}^+(T)$ be the subgroup of index 2 of $\operatorname{Aut}(T)$ preserving the bicoloring of the tree for which adjacent vertices have distinct colours.

Let $\Gamma$ be a lattice in $G:=\operatorname{Aut}^+(T)$.

There are a number of open problems concerning whether the commensurator $\operatorname{Comm}_G(\Gamma)$ is discrete, or dense.

In the case where $\Gamma$ is uniform, the commensurator is known to be dense in $\operatorname{Aut}^+(T)$.  This is also true for non-uniform lattices of Nagao type (Abramenko–Rémy).

In any of these cases or in any specific examples, is the commensurator $\operatorname{Comm}_G(\Gamma)$ known to be simple?

Comment: $\mathrm{Aut}(T)$ surjects on the cyclic group $C_2$, and hence so do its dense subgroups, so no dense subgroup can be simple. Maybe you want to ask about the the commensurator in $\mathrm{Aut}(T)^+$, the subgroup of index 2 (preserving the bicoloring of the tree for which adjacent vertices have distinct colors)— by the way, biregular trees is probably the right setting for such a question.

Comment: I'd be tempted to e-mail Pierre-Emmanuel Caprace about this.  This abstract seems relevant: https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/research/events/2017-18/symposium/symp_seminars/caprace.pdf .

Comment: @YCor Ah yes, sorry I should have stated that.

Comment: @HJRW the linked abstract is about the abstract commensurator, which is a much larger group. Indeed in $\mathrm{Aut}(T)$, the prime orders of elements are bounded (by $n$), while in the abstract commensurator, there are elements of arbitrary large prime order (clear since the abstract commensurator contains $\mathrm{Aut}(F_k)$ for every $k$ hence contains copies of all finite groups). Hence, the commensurator of every cocompact lattice $\Gamma$ in $\mathrm{Aut}(T_n)$ has infinite index in the abstract commensurator of $\Gamma$.

Comment: @YCor -- yes, I'm aware that they're different groups.

Comment: @HJRW I've added a partial answer based on an appendix of a paper of Caprace, which I believe is related to that talk abstract.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer which follows from Henry Wilton's (@HJRW) comment.  In the appendix of the paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.01091) (arXiv 1712.01091) Caprace proves:

For $m\geq 3$, consider the commensurator ${\rm Comm}_{{\rm Aut}(T)}(W_m)$ of the free Coxeter group $W_m$ of rank $m$, where $T$ is the Cayley tree.  Then,

1. ${\rm Comm}_{{\rm Aut}(T)}(W_m)$ is almost simple
2. ${\rm Comm}_{{\rm Aut}(T)}(W_m)$ contains a simple subgroup $B$ such that $[W_m : B \cap W_m] < \infty$.